# Worklight LTPA SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-mobilefirst, ltpa

I am creating a SSO application and I have set all the setting on WebSphere Application server and it's working fine and genrating a Token now my question is if I want to use same LTPA token in another application that are hosted in same server, Can i do this ? If yes can you give me any hint(or and sample code) how to pass the Token ? when ever I am accessing secure content in 2nd app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, cookies are not shared between apps. To make this question even trickier, you would have a hard time using Device provisioning if the WAS is protecting worklight behind LTPA (you cannot provision with Worklight Server, if you can't access it without an LTPA token).

One thing you could try is using a native storage mechanism, where you would write to device storage that can be accessed by both apps. You may have to write your own cordova plugins for this, but check around the open source world first, if possible. Your apps then read the file containing your LTPA token. If it exists, you would set the cookie before your app connects to the worklight server. If the token expires, you will be fine, since the server will ask you to login. After a login, you should store the token in that file for later use.

There may be easier ways than what I just suggested (and can be made much more secure), but this is the solution that comes to mind at the moment.